# Inner didSet protection bizarrely extends to the whole class?

Tags: swift, properties, didset, property-observer

It's well-known that, of course, didSet will not run on the same object again from inside a didSet. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363170/why-no-infinite-loop-in-didset).)

However. It seems that: **the restriction applies not only to that object, but to maybe *any object of the same class***.

Here are copy-paste test cases for Playground.

```
class C {
    var Test: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("test.")
            for c in r {
                c.Test = true
            }
        }
    }
    var r:[C] = []
}
var a:C = C()
var b:C = C()
var c:C = C()
a.r = [b, c]
a.Test = false
```

Does not work!

```
class C {
    var Test2: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("test2.")
            global.Test2 = true
        }
    }
}
var global:C = C()
var a:C = C()
a.Test2 = false
```

Does not work!

1. Is this a Swift bug?
2. If not, **what is the actual restriction**?  It won't run ANY didSet (whatsoever) that starts from a didSet?; the same identical class?; the same super class?; or?
3. Where exactly is this explained in the doco?

WTF. One needs to know ... what is the actual restriction specifically?

Comment: Theoretically one of the children could be itself. meaning an infinite loop could still occur. Might be a bug, might be a feature It's not an answer, hence the reason it's in the comments :)

Comment: @JoeBlow: This comment in the [Swift source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/AST/Decl.cpp#L1072) might be relevant:  *"Observing member are accessed directly from within their didSet/willSet specifiers.  This prevents assignments from becoming infinite loops."* You could also try to ask at the swift-users mailing list, where people from the Swift team are regularly contributing.

Comment: This looks like the same question: [Why no Infinite loop in didSet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363170/why-no-infinite-loop-in-didset).

Comment: I completely agree that the Swift implementation is surprising and I would prefer an infinite loop there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug [SR-419](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-419).

From the comment on the bug:

> Ugh. We really need to check that the base of the property access is statically `self`.

and from my experiments it seems that the `didSet` observer is not invoked only if you set the same property on any object. If you set any other property (even on the same object), the observer is invoked correctly.

```
class A {
    var name: String
    var related: A?
    var property1: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("\(name), setting property 1: \(property1)")

            self.property2 = 100 * property1
            related?.property1 = 10 * property1
            related?.property2 = 100 * property1
        }
    }
    var property2: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("\(name), setting property 2: \(property2)")
        }
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let a = A(name: "Base")
a.related = A(name: "Related")
a.property1 = 2
```

Output:

> Base, setting property 1: 2
>   Base, setting property 2: 200
>   Related, setting property 2: 200

when the expected output should be:

> Base, setting property 1: 2
>   Base, setting property 2: 200
>   Related, setting property 1: 20
>   Related, setting property 2: 2000
>   Related, setting property 2: 200

It seems you also need to assign that property *directly* from the observer. Once you enter another function (or observer), the observers start working again:

```
var property1: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        print("\(name), setting property 1: \(property1)")

        onSet()
    }
}

...    
func onSet() {
    self.property2 = 100 * property1
    related?.property1 = 10 * property1
    related?.property2 = 100 * property1
}
```

And that is the best **workaround**.

Another workaround (thanks [@Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976878/hamish)) is to wrap nested assignments into an immediately executed closure:

```
var property1: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
       {
           self.property2 = 100 * property1
           related?.property1 = 10 * property1
           related?.property2 = 100 * property1
       }()
    }
}
```

Depending on code before the closure, you might have to wrap it into parenthesis or insert a semicolon after the preceding statement.

Comment: @JoeBlow From my testing it works correctly for unrelated properties. Also, if you call `property1.didSet` from `property2.didSet` which is called from `property1.didSet` then you get a nice infinite loop like expected. I haven't tested subclasses but I think it would work the same - it's still the same property.

Comment: Another interesting workaround – using an immediately-executed closure: `_ = { self.related?.property1 = 10 * self.property1 }()` (for some reason, Swift doesn't like it if you don't say `_ = `).

Comment: @Hamish you would have to add a manual return to make it return void :)

Comment: @Sulthan Not sure I follow – an assignment returns `Void` (although in this case it's an optional chain assignment, so `Void?`). Thus the closure should be inferred to be a `() -> Void?` and all should be well. Swift however complains that it's expecting a `do {...}` block, but adding a `_ =` makes the error go away. Adding a `; return` in the closure doesn't help.

Comment: @Hamish Sorry, I was reading wrong from mobile. You would have to wrap the block into parenthesis `({ ... })()` otherwise the syntax analyzer will have a hard time figuring it's a closure.

Comment: @Sulthan Yeah, I'm aware there's various corner cases with the syntax parser, my point was that `{ self.related?.property1 = 10 * self.property1 }()` should be valid – although adding parenthesis is a good suggestion to work around it (a workaround to implement a workaround :) )

Comment: @Hamish You can also make `{ ... }` to be a closure by adding `{ () -> Void in ... }`, however you can have other collisions because the compiler can consider it a trailing closure for a previous expression.

Comment: @Sulthan Ah, that seems to be it – if there's no previous statement, then it compiles fine (you don't need to add `() -> Void in`). You can also fix it by adding a semicolon to the previous statement, forcing the parser to treat them separately.

Comment: @Hamish Ah, didn't think of semicolon.

Comment: @JoeBlow True but it's not that common to have classes that hold classes of the same type.

Comment: @JoeBlow I did consider writing an answer, but decided against it due to the fact that Sulthan and Martin have already covered the why and what of the matter – and that's what I thought your question was asking for (to quote you: "*PS, obviously, I know how to write a workaround here*"). I was really just hoping Sulthan would add the workaround as an addendum to his answer :)

Comment: @Hamish I have added that now.

Comment: FYI this will be fixed in Swift 5 :)